# I can't see my images in my smartphone Android

Tags: ionic2

I have a problem because after install my app in my smartphone Android, I can't see any image. I have all my images in "www/img". Running in Google Chrome I can see all my images.
My icon app I can see. I executed "ionic resources --icon" for de resolution, I guess that  I would have to do the same with other images. Somebody know how can I do that?
Thanks in advance.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Images and other assets should be in the `app` folder, in a location you should choose. 
On the other hand, in order for them to be shown, they should also be in the `www/build` folder.
The `build` folder is recreated every time you use `ionic build` or `ionic run` on a device.

What happens is that ionic runs gulp tasks specified in `gulpfile.js`. 
The default `gulpfile` comes with a task that compiles the sass files, the js and the html.
If you want to add a task for your images, you can add something similar to:

```
gulp.task('images', function() {
    return gulp.src(['app/assets/images/**/*'])
        .pipe(gulp.dest('www/build/assets/images'));
});
```

The above code will take all images in the `app/assets/images` and will copy them to the `build/assets/images` directory whenever you build the project.
What is left to do now though is to add the `images` task to the `runSequence`:

```
gulp.task('watch', ['clean'], function(done){
  runSequence(
    ['sass', 'html', 'fonts', 'scripts'],
    function(){
      gulpWatch('app/**/*.scss', function(){ gulp.start('sass'); });
      gulpWatch('app/**/*.html', function(){ gulp.start('html'); });
      gulpWatch('app/**/*.json', function(){ gulp.start('data'); });
      buildBrowserify({ watch: true }).on('end', done);
    }
  );
});

gulp.task('build', ['clean'], function(done){
  runSequence(
    ['sass', 'html', 'fonts', 'scripts','images'],
    function(){
      buildBrowserify({
        minify: isRelease,
        browserifyOptions: {
          debug: !isRelease
        },
        uglifyOptions: {
          mangle: false
        }
      }).on('end', done);
    }
  );
});
```

You can read more about gulp [here](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md)